# Two different product results from a percentage and decimal counterpart

Tags: percentages

Why am I getting two different products when I multiply 190,690,000 and 14.518% and 190,690,000 and .14518.

The former is 27,684,386.41 and the latter is 27,684,374.20.

Am I going crazy?

Comment: The second result is correct and the first is incorrect, which you can confirm e.g. using WolframAlpha. Where are you performing these multiplications? Possibly whatever you're using rounds percentages.

Comment: Ok. I get it. If I expand the number of decimal places then the numbers end up being different by 100 millionths. So such a relatively negligble difference, but I imagine a world a difference in some aspects.

Comment: If you are consistently getting the same values you are going crazy.  If you are getting the different results once you are just making an entry error.    I suppose it *is* possible that a calculator may be programmed to make roundings  for percentages differently the it make rounding for others that cause the discrepancy but that seems unlikely.  If we comes to worse multiply $19069 \times 14518$ and manually figure out the decimal place. (BTW as $8\times 9$ ends with $2$ the first figure must be wrong).

Comment: Qiaochu Yuan - the funny thing is I got that percentage by dividing the first number by the 190 million. However, when I went to just do some verification I ended up getting the second number. That's what ended up throwing me off. Finally I saw that the second number is actually spot on to the percentage. However the first number just ended up being different by three 100 millionths. Thank you for responding.